# Strategy for busy WCF service

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0

I've got a really busy self-hosted WCF server that requires 2000+ clients to update their status on a frequent basis.  What I'm finding is that the CPU utilization of the server is sitting at around 70% constantly, and the clients have a 50% chance of actually getting a connection to the server.  They will timeout after 60 seconds. This is problematic because if the server doesn't hear back from a client, it'll assume the client is offline.

I've implemented throttling so I can adjust concurrent connections/sessions/etc., but if I'm not mistaken, increasing this will only lead to higher CPU utilization and worse connectivity problems. Right?

Will increasing the timeout to something more than 60 seconds help? I'm not exactly sure how it works, but will a client sit in a type of queue until the server can field the request? Or is it best to set the timeout to something smaller and make the client check in more often if it can't get connected (this seems like it could only make the problem worse in a sense)?

Comment: Why does the server know anything about the client?

Comment: Is the biggest problem that you need to have reliable messaging? i.e. need to make sure that your messages always get through?

Comment: Terry - Yes, the server keeps track of a list of computers that are known to be online. If a client doesn't report in, the server marks it as offline and an admin is notified to go look into it. Obviously, if the client can't talk to the server, then a bunch of false "offlines" are going to be reported.

Answer (score 1):

If it's really important for the server to know if the client is still connected, I don't think relying solely on WCF is your best bet for that.

Maybe your server should have some sort of ping mechanism that either allows it to ping client machines based on some sort of timer or vice versa.

If you're super concerned about the messages always getting through, no matter what, then I suggest exploring Reliable services.  Check out the `enableReliableSession` behavior attribute.  I suggest reading through at least the first chapter in Juval Lowy's *Programming WCF Services* which is available for free as the Kindle sample of the book.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing the timeout *may* help, but probably not much, and the Amazing Ever-Increasing Timeout is kind of a motif on http://www.thedailywtf.com . Making the client hammer the server if it can't get through the first time is guaranteed to cause pain.

If all that you care about is knowing whether the client is there, might it be practical to go down a layer or two, and have the client send you an HTTP POST once in a while? WCF requires some active back-and-forth, but a POST can just lay there until your server has time to deal with it, and the client can just send it and forget about it.

Comment: Would using WCF to host a json-style service help any here? That's also an HTTP post, but does it require some type of back & forth that a NetTCP WCF service would have?